Shinouy makom and adoption of new minhagim
As we know, a person who moves from one makom (location) to another makom must follow the minhag of the new makom.
Is the adoption considered as a shinouy makom like a wife who left the house of her father for example?

Doesn't everything just depend on the metzius of any particular case?

The fact is if a man adopted the son of his wife from a previous relation, is there a concept of shinuy makom for.the child?

As we see that the wife of a Kohen is considered as making a shinouy makom as she can ate teroumah for exemple.

@חיים kohen wife teruma doesn't have to do with shinui makom since even an arusa can eat truma (mideoraita) even though she hasn't changed makom yet

OKay thank you Double AA.    so when we talk about shinouy makom is the shinouy minhag for ever or if the person moves then to a new makom where there is minhag avot, she has to return to it?

You started with a wrong assertion. Minhag Hamakom only applied when there was one rabbi, one Beis Din, and one Shul in the whole place. If there are two rabbis/shuls, you can always get away with "I follow the other tradition". For example, the Hassidim who came to Jerusalem ended up keeping their traditions rather than adopting local Sefardic ones.

The concept of "minhagim" is very almost completely lost in our current melting pot world. One does not need to keep his father's stringencies or personal minhagim. Minhagim were based on location, eg your community did not work erev Pesach (P'sachim 4:1). When you moved to a new place you had to adhere to the new community standards (see more here). If there were two courts ie communities in one town, you can choose whichever one you want (שני בתי דינין, Rav Yevamot 1:4).
If a child moves to a new community then he must adhere to new community's minhagim whether he was adopted or not. If there are 2 communities then the child can technically keep whichever community's minhagim but I doubt it is practical or recommended to be different that the adopted family.

Arizal said in Shaarey Kavanot Inyan Nusach Tefila that one must follows his father's minhaguim which is related perhaps to his tribe.

i dont find any "Inyan Nusach Tefila" in the table of contents but i have heard that the arizal made his own nusach of tefillah so it fulfils all the different nuschaot of the tribes. was the question was specifically about tefillah? either way, almost no one nowadays keeps the authentic nosach of their own town in the old country. even in the old country most just used whatever siddur was available. nowadays many ashkenazim default to the minhagim of their yeshiva and many sefardim switched to hacham ovadia
